# How to turn on usb charge only mode programatically if the mode is file transfer in android?

Tags: android, usb, mtp, usb-modeswitch

I will have to show this type of dialog if my device is connected to usb and I want to access the app.
Here this dialog shows
-Click to Charge Only will automatically set the USB protocol to Charge only mode and i can not access files from my phone

Can Anyone help me to achieve this feature?

[image]

I have used to get device list but device list is empty. But still i dont thing this will solve my problem

```
  for (entry in usbDeviceList.entries) {
            val usbDevice = entry.value

            // Check the USB device's connection mode
            val usbConfiguration = usbDevice.getConfiguration(0)
            val usbInterface = usbConfiguration.getInterface(0)
            val usbInterfaceClass = usbInterface.interfaceClass

            // Check if the interface class indicates MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)
            if (usbInterfaceClass == 6) {
                // The device is in MTP mode (File Transfer mode)
                // You can perform file transfer operations here
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "(File Transfer mode)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } else {
                // The device is not in MTP mode
                // Handle the mode accordingly
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "MTP mode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```